# Lavaan error: number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Tags: r, statistics, r-lavaan

I am a bit confused with an error message I get from running a cfa with the lavaan package:

1st I enter 3 factors (task, relationship, change) and the underlying items

```
yukl.model <- '

task =~ df$yukl_task_1 + df$yukl_task_2 + df$yukl_task_3 + df$yukl_task_4 + df$yukl_task_5

relationship =~ df$yukl_rel_1 + df$yukl_rel_2 + df$yukl_rel_3 + df$yukl_rel_4 + df$yukl_rel_5 + df$yukl_rel_6

change =~ df$yukl_change_1 + df$yukl_change_2 + df$yukl_change_3'
```

And then I try to fit them. (df is the name of my data frame. The items are from that data frame)

```
fit <- cfa(yukl.model, data=df)
```

But all I get is this error message: "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"

There are no NAs in my code and I don't understand where I am trying to "replace" items. 
Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You have likely confused the syntax parser by including the reference to you data frame in each observed variable name. This is redundant with specifying your data frame within the cfa() call. Strip out the "df$" from your model syntax and I believe the issue will be resolved.